# Slideshow, slide image in as other slides out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I'm currently working on a jquery slide show using the show and hide function and in general it works pritty well. What i can't figure out is how to make an image slide in at the same time as the first image slides out. It just waits for the first image to slide out before sliding in the next one. What i want is for an image to slide in the same time as the other slides out and not have the image sliding in having to wait for the first image to be done with it's out sliding.

It feels like i'm making a misstake somewhere..

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
        <a href="https://google.com"><img id="1" src="bilder/partner.jpg" type="jpg/png">
        <a href="https://msn.com"><img id="2" src="bilder/värmeplatta.jpg" type="jpg/png">
        <a href="https://twitter.com"><img id="3" src="bilder/Img3.jpg" type="jpg/png">
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider
        {
            width:600px;
            height:300px;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin: auto;
            background-color:white;
            background-image:url(LoadingLogo.gif);
            background-size:50px 50px;
            background-position:center;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            border:2px solid;
        }
        .slider img
        {
            width:600px;
            height:300px;
            display:none;
        }
```

**Javascript**

```
 function Slider()
                {
                    $("#1").show("slide",{direction:'right'},800);
                    $("#1").delay(4500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},800);

                    var sc=$(".slider img").size();
                    var count=2;

                    setInterval(function()
                    {
                        $("#"+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'},800);
                        $("#"+count).delay(4500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},800);

                        if(count==sc)
                            count=1;
                        else
                            count=count+1;  
                    },6100)
                }
```

Comment: remove .delay(4500) part

Comment: The .delay(4500) is what makes the image stay for 4.5 secounds. Removing that only resault in the image just sliding in and directly out again.

Answer (score 0):

I can not create a fiddle but try to use this code instead of provided:

```
function Slider() {

$("#1").show("slide",{direction:'right'},800);

var slideCount = $('.slider').find('img').length,
    prevSlide = 1,
    activeSlide = 2;

    setInterval(function() {

        $('#' + prevSlide ).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},800);

        $('#' + activeSlide ).show('slide',{direction:'right'},800);

        activeSlide++;
        prevSlide = activeSlide - 1;

        if( activeSlide === slideCount )
            activeSlide = 1;

        if( prevSlide === 0 )
            prevSlide = slideCount;

   },6100)
}
```